# Finding html elements by id in Java code

Tags: java, jquery, expression

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience retrieving elements by id for a given string of html in a performant way. I'm writing a method that takes two arguments:

```
public String getFilteredHtml(String html, Set<String> ids)
```

The method will return the concatenated html of elements matching the ids passed in. Currently I am using JSoup to accomplish this by parsing the html into a document, and either looping through the ids and appending the result of `document.getElementById`, or using a selector that looks like `[id=id1],[id=id2]` etc, which works fine with comparable performance between the two.

However I couldn't help but notice that if while parsing an html document, a map containing String id > Element was kept the lookup would much be faster. Does anyone know of a library that has this functionality, or a way to go about implementing it myself? Or any other ways that might accomplish this faster?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. can you give a little more detail? what exactly are you doing with the elements you get by id from the HTML string?

Comment: This is an ajax filter, it will take html generated from the servlet, and strip it down to only return the fragments that need to be updated on the page through ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a SAX based HTML parser and build your map while the document is getting parsed. Something like [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) or [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) for example. I'm not sure how much faster it would be though, you'd have to benchmark.

Comment: Seems like a custom sax parser is the best way to go about it, even though its pretty low level. I'll give it a try.